# JavaScript-less Fallback for HTML Element not supported by browsers

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to begin using the `main` element. I understand that there are things similar to HTML5 shiv, that make it usable in browsers that don't yet support it, but all of these workarounds require JavaScript to be enabled.

What happens if JavaScript is disabled in the browser, or the browser does not support JavaScript. How can we use a fallback for the main element when the main element is already there by default?

---

I have one solution, but I am not sure if it is the right way to go about it:

If you want to use the `main` element, use JavaScript to insert it into the document, and make sure that you make it the container for its children elements. Then put your `<div id="main"></div>` in `<noscript>` tags.

Is this the right way to go for fallbacks for HTML elements in cases where JavaScript may be disabled?

Comment: I think people with JS disabled are negligible. And if they decide to do so, and still want websites to be displayed correctly, they can use newer browsers that support html5.

Comment: I also believe that they are negligible. However, I still like to try as best as I can to accommodate them. @Oriol, are you aware of any place that has statistics on JavaScript usage in browsers?

Comment: Not sure about JavaScript usage, but http://gs.statcounter.com has lots of browser statistics.

Comment: Why not just use a div with a role of main (for screen readers), like so: `<div id="main" role="main"></div>`?

Answer (score 1):

Virtually all browsers support unknown elements. For example, you can have `<xyz>Inner Content</xyz>` and will still see the "Inner Content". So, all you need to do is ensure you have a CSS styling for main so that main consistently appears as a block, even on browsers that don't know about it:

```
main { display: block; }
```

I would also add a role="main" attribute to give browsers not familiar with  a better chance of identifying the element as the main content area:

```
<main role="main">
```